# is it possible for a Pandas dataframe to have blanks for missing values instead of NaN or 0?

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pandas

I am importing table data that has some missing values. I'm putting into a dataframe and writing to Excel with xlsxwriter. For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':["33","34", ""], 'b':["35","", "55"]})
```

[image]

I would like to leave them as empty cells in Excel but this is only possible in Pandas with an "object" datatype (like a string). I want to use them as integer but then I would need to fillna() as NaN or 0.

Is it impossible to have an integer datatype with empty cells? It seems like it.

Comment: No. Integer dtypes can only hold, well, Integers. A blank isn't an integer so you can only do so if the column is object, which I'd vehemently argue against.

Comment: That being said, when you're working with pandas you _should_ do what's best for pandas, and _mostly_ forget about the quirks of the other languages/programs. If you need the output to look specific for some other application or input then you format at the _very end_. For example, [`df.to_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) has a default `na_rep = ''` such that when you write to excel all of those `NaN`s in your pandas DataFrame are now empty when you open that file in excel. So best of both worlds.

Comment: na_rep works perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Alollz had the right solution - use df.to_excel(na_rep = '')

Comment: Actually you don't even need na_rep - if the blanks are np.nan and dataframe is a dtype integer or float, it will write to Excel as that dtype and leave those cells blank. It doesn't write "np.nan". The problem above is my dataframe was text string.